Probability distribution function that governs the number of points in histogram bins. Consistency between multiple dimensions?
Let's have a continuous random variable $x$ with some probability density function $f(x)$. A bin is given by an interval $[x_1, x_2)$. Given a total number of points $N$ generated from the PDF $f(x)$, what is the distribution of the number of points falling within the bin?
My line of thinking goes: the bin acts like a click counter with some mean probability $p$ given by
$$
p = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x) \mathrm{d}x
$$
and so the probability $P(n|p)$ is Poisson distribution,
$$
P (n | p) = \frac{\lambda^n e^{-\lambda}}{n!}, \quad \lambda \equiv \langle n \rangle = N p
$$
It seems to me that this would be the answer someone would intuitively give, but I see two immediate issues with this:

The Poisson distribution $P(n | p)$ is nonzero for $n > 0$ even if $p = 0$. However, if $p = 0$ (the PDF $f(x)$ is zero throughout the whole bin $[x_1, x_2)$), the distribution for $n$ must be $P (n | 0) = \delta_{n}$, i.e. either 1 if $n = 1$ or 0 otherwise.

The probability that $n$ is larger than $N$ must be zero. Again, the Poisson distribution does not adhere to this.


For these reasons, I'm thinking we need to consider the probability outside the bin, which is $1 - p$. Then, I would say, if each bin is rougly "Poisson-like", we can start off by assuming that the distribution in each bin is Poisson, but together, the bins are constrained by the condition that the total number of events is $N$, so
$$
P (n | p) \propto \frac{(N p)^n e^{-N p}}{n!} \frac{(N p)^{n_{\text{out}}} e^{-N p_{\text{out}}}}{n_{\text{out}}!} \delta_{n + n_{\text{out}} - N} = \frac{(N p)^n}{n!} \frac{(N (1-p))^{N-n}}{(N - n)!}
$$
Together with normalization, this turns out to be
$$
P (n | p) = \binom{N}{n} p^n (1 - p)^{N-n}
$$
This distribution exhibits correct behavior in both cases: when $p = 0$, the distribution is equal to $\delta_n$ and $P(n | p) = 0$ when $n > N$.
Questions:

how do we rigorously prove this is the correct distribution? The appearance of the Poisson distribution seems arbitrary

Can we extend this for a whole "histogram" (collection of bins)? Let the bins be numbered and correspond to intervals $\text{bin}_1 = [x_1, x_2), \text{bin}_2 = [x_2, x_3), \cdots, \text{bin}_k = [x_k, x_{k+1})$. Can we now say
$$
P (n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_k | p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_k) \propto \frac{\lambda_1^{n_1} e^{-\lambda_1}}{n_1!} \frac{\lambda_2^{n_2} e^{-\lambda_2}}{n_2!} \cdots \frac{\lambda_k^{n_k} e^{-\lambda_k}}{n_k!} \delta (n_1 + n_2 + \cdots + n_k - N)
$$
with $\lambda_i = N p_i$? This is up to the normalization, which turns out to be $N! / (N^N e^{-N})$.

how would this be consistent across dimensions? What I mean, let's have two independent random variables, $x, y$, drawn from PDFs $f_x(x), f_y(y)$ with the joint PDF $f_{(x,y)}(x,y)$ equal to $f_x(x) f_y(y)$. What would be the probability distribution governing the number of events in



one-dimensional bins $[x_1, x_2)$, $[y_1, y_2)$ for each variable separately

two dimensional bin $[x_1, x_2) \times [y_1, y_2)$,

how is the distribution of events in the two-dimensional bin related to the distributions of events in individual bins? I.e., is the probability of some number of events in the bin, $N_{x,y}$ given by the marginalized probabilities
$$
N_{x,y} \overset{?}{=} N p_x p_y \quad \to \quad P (N_{x,y}) \overset{?}{=} P (N_x | p_x) P (N_y | p_y)
$$
or is it more complicated than that?


They should be independent, right? Do we expect that $\langle N_{x,y} \rangle = \langle n_x \rangle \langle n_y \rangle$? Do we expect $\langle (n_{x,y} - n_x n_y / N)^2 \rangle = 0$? I would say latter can't be expected for finite number of total points in the dataset, because of noise. If I generate a random set of 2D points (each component individually from a Gaussian), I get a nonzero value of $p_{x,y} - p_x p_y$ for some bin just because due to noise the bins become a bit correlated, despite the ideal PDF of $x,y$ being uncorrelated.
To be clear, I see two options: either the individual 2D bins are distributed according to the distribution derived above
$$
P (n_{1,1}, n_{1,2}, \cdots, n_{k_x, k_y}) \propto \prod_{\text{bins }(i,j)}\frac{(N p_i p_j)^{n_{i,j}} e^{-N p_i p_j}}{n_{i,j}!} \delta_{\sum_{i,j} n_{i,j} - N}
$$
or the 1D bins are distributed separately and there is a relation $n_{i,j} = n_i n_j / N$, which, I don't think is true (I wouldn't be able to get a nonzero difference by generating a finite amount of points).
EDIT: First off, I recognized that the distribution I got for one bin is the binomial distribution and it is the "correct" one (not sure how we'd derive it). I think it's now a bit clearer to me what the apparent problem is:

if we rely on the fact that $n_x, n_y$ are independent random variables (because they're bin counts for two independent variables), then we can say
$$
n_{x,y} = n_x n_y / N
$$
but the product of two binomially distributed random variables isn't a "pretty" distribution. For high $N$ it seems to tend to a Gaussian, though

on the other hand, if we take the 2D bin and forget about the 1D cases, we should be able to write
$$
P (n = n_{x,y} | p = p_{x,y}) = \binom{N}{n} p^n (1-p)^{N - n}
$$
with $p = p_{x,y} = p_x p_y$, since the 2D bin adheres to this idea just as the 1D histogram. But that would prove, that the product of two independent binomial variables is also distributed binomially with the resulting $p$ being the product of the individual $p_x, p_y$. But this post seems to be implying that the product of random binomial variables isn't distributed according to some known distribution that could be explicitly written. I think $n_{x,y}$ indeed is distributed binomially, but in a real dataset, it cannot be written in terms of $n_x, n_y$ even if (ideally) $p_{x,y} = p_x p_y$, due to the noise.

it would then be interesting to know the joint distribution $P (n_{x,y}, n_x, n_y)$. Variables $n_x$, $n_y$ are independent, but $n_{x,y}$ is not independent of $n_x, n_y$.

due to this, we can easily calculate $\langle n_{x,y} \rangle = \frac{1}{N} \langle n_x \rangle \langle n_y \rangle$, but calculating $\langle (n_{x,y} - n_x n_y / N)^2 \rangle$ seems to be much harder.



First, I'd like to recognize that the function I derived is indeed correct - it is the binomial (or multinomial) distribution which governs the probability distribution of the number of events within individual bins. Here bins can be a single bin, in which case there's actually two bins total: the bin we're focusing on and "everything else" (which is also a bin) and the probability is given by
$$
P (n \in \text{bin} | p) = \binom{N}{n} p^n (1-p)^{N-n}
$$
Considering individual events to be uncorrelated (if we generate events from a certain 1D PDF one after another, we assume the value of the next one is not dependent on the previous), there's $\binom{N}{n}$ ways to distribute $n$ events out of $N$ into a bin and the probability of that happening $n$ times is $p^n$. On the other hand, the probability it does not happen for the rest of the $N - n$ bins is $p^{N-n}$. The derivation for multinomial works similarly, the formula reads
$$
P (n_1, \cdots, n_k | p_1, \cdots, p_k) = \frac{n!}{n_1! \cdots n_k!} p_1^{n_1} \cdots p_k^{n_k} \delta_{n_1 + \cdots + n_k - N}
$$
assuming $p_1 + \cdots + p_n = 1$ (we covered the whole probability space with the bins).
Now, $N_{x,y}$ is indeed dependent on $N_x$ and $N_y$. There is nothing special about 1D or 2D histograms/bins regardless if the 2D variables are correlated or uncorrelated. For that reason, $\langle N_{x,y} \rangle = N p_{x,y}$ and $\langle N_x \rangle = N p_x$. However, let's look at $\langle N_{x,y} N_x \rangle$. For this, we split the histogram into three parts, better seen on this picture:


the bin of the of interest, containing $N_{x,y}$ number of events.

the column containing $N_{x,y}$, minus the previous bin. This bin will be called $N_{i,j^\prime \neq j}$ and we can easily see the following relation
$$
N_{x,y} + N_{i,j^\prime \neq j} = N_x
$$

everything else. We can see, that these three bins sum up to $N$
$$
N_{x,y} + N_{i,j^\prime \neq j} + N_{\text{rest}} = N
$$


The random variables $N_{x,y}, N_{i,j^\prime \neq j}, N_{\text{rest}}$ are complementary bins in a histogram, they are thus distributed according to the multinomial (trinomial?) distribution:
$$
P (n_1 = N_{x,y}, n_2 = N_{i,j^\prime \neq j}, n_3 = N_{\text{rest}}) = \frac{N!}{n_1! n_2! n_3!} p_1^{n_1} p_2^{n_2} p_3^{n_3} \delta_{n_1 + n_2 + n_3 - N}
$$
We can examine the mean value $\langle N_{x,y} N_x \rangle$
$$
\langle N_{x,y} N_x \rangle = \langle N_{x,y} (N_{x,y} + N_{i, j^\prime \neq j}) \rangle = \langle N_{x,y}^2 \rangle + \langle N_{x,y} N_{i, j^\prime \neq j} \rangle
$$
Here we can use the properties of the multinomial distribution, or write down a generating function that can help us with these, but the result is
$$
\langle N_{x,y} N_x \rangle - \langle N_{x,y} \rangle \langle N_x \rangle = N^2 p_{x,y}^2 + N p_{x,y} (1 - p_x)
$$
This derivation assumed nothing about the dependence between $x$ and $y$. But even if we assume $p_{x,y} = p_x p_y$ (independence), this difference is not zero.
I still can't derive the joint distribution for $N_{x,y}, N_x, N_y$.
